# TypeError: Failed to execute 'addTrack' on 'MediaStream': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStreamTrack'

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediastream

I am trying to add and remove an audio track from a stream.
The removeTrack function works but the addTrack function throws the error below when it is called

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addTrack' on 'MediaStream': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStreamTrack'.
    at addAudio (video.jsx:22)
    at HTMLButtonElement.document.querySelector.onclick (video.jsx:32)
```

Below Is My Code

```
    componentDidMount = () => {
        var Mstream;
        const video = document.querySelector("video")
        const hasMedia = () => {
            return navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
        }

        const fetchMedia = () => {
            var constraints = { video: true, audio: true }
            navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, (stream) => {
                Mstream = stream
                video.srcObject = stream
            }, (error) => { })
        }

        const addAudio = () => {
            console.log("Adding")
            const audioTracks = Mstream.getAudioTracks()
            Mstream.addTrack(audioTracks[0])
            console.log('Added')
        }

        const removeAudio = () => {
            console.log('removing')
            const audioTracks = Mstream.getAudioTracks()
            Mstream.removeTrack(audioTracks[0])
            console.log('Removed')
        }
        document.querySelector("button#add").onclick = () => addAudio()

        document.querySelector("button#remove").onclick = () => removeAudio()
        hasMedia() && fetchMedia()
    }
```

## EDIT

But it still returns the same error with the addTrack function

```
        const addAudio = () => {
            console.log("Adding")
            const audioTracks = Mstream.getAudioTracks()
            if(audioTracks.length <= 0){
                Mstream.addTrack(audioTracks[0])
                console.log("Track Added")
            }
            else{
                console.log("Cannot Add Track")
            }

        }

        const removeAudio = () => {
            console.log('removing')
            const audioTracks = Mstream.getAudioTracks()
            if (audioTracks.length > 0) {
                Mstream.removeTrack(audioTracks[0])
            }
            else {
                console.log("Cannot Remove It")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `MediaStream.getAudioTracks()` method returns an array of `MediaStreamTrack` objects. But, it provides no guarantee that there are any elements in the array. `audioTracks[0]` may be `undefined`, which would cause this error to occur.

Comment: @hackingtechhome just check that the returned Array has a `length` before trying to call addTrack

Comment: I have edited the question and added the new code which i used but still it returns the same error.
Please have a look above

Comment: @hackingtechhome you got it wrong: if length is below or equal to zero, you cannot use addTrack. Replace <= to >.